# How to import time series data from web?

Tags: python, pandas-datareader

I am reading a book about Python and one of the examples is as such.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as pdr

goog = pdr.DataReader('GOOG', data_source='google',start='3/14/2009', end='4/14/2014')
goog.tail()
```

Running that gives me this error message: ''utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 46787: invalid start byte'.  What does this mean?  This seems like it should be a pretty simple thing.

Comment: I'm not going to be able to help you to reproduce the problem but please state what versions (python) you use, what kernel you are on and so on.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6 and working in the Spyder environment.